# Import error DAG airflow cannot import name 'serialization'

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver

I have written a Dag file with contain ssh hook implementation.
I get import error in the DAG file

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 91, in 
> from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/dsskey.py", line 25, in 
> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
> ImportError: cannot import name 'serialization'

[image]

how to resolve this?

thanks in advance
Sundar

Comment: Show your dag code.

Comment: added the dag code