# test ssh connection failed in airflow

Tags: airflow

we have added ssh connection in airflow connections, while testing it we get error like
'Hook SSHHook doesn't implement or inherit test_connection method'

[image: ssh hook error]

Comment: Airflow version? did you tried to use the connection with SSHOperator? According to the error its seems that SSH connections just don't have the test functionality

Comment: version 2.2.4. yes I created DAG also, it shows me a different error as follows
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71762341/import-error-dag-airflow-cannot-import-name-serialization

Answer (score 3):

Test button in the UI works only with Hooks that implemented `test_connection`. This means that you can not test the connection with the UI and you will have to create some DAG to test it.

In newer airflow versions the button will be disabled for connections/hooks that doesn't support this functionality (See [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/19792))